# IEnumerable and console.writeline

Tags: c#, linq, console, ienumerable

I have this simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NuLabsEntities db = new NuLabsEntities();

            IEnumerable<company> companies = from cmp in db.company select cmp;

            foreach (var row in companies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(companies);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

I know it's a basic question: I'm learning c#

But i don't understand why, after creating with ado.net an edmx file and try running this simple code it returns me the following query instead of the result of a list of rows of the company table:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[companyId] AS [companyId],
    [Extent1].[labirintoCodiceCliente] AS [labirintoCodiceCliente],
    [Extent1].[labirintoCodiceAteco2007] AS [labirintoCodiceAteco2007],
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name],
    [Extent1].[doc] AS [doc],
    [Extent1].[notes] AS [notes],
    [Extent1].[vatNumber] AS [vatNumber],
    [Extent1].[taxCode] AS [taxCode],
    [Extent1].[LabirintoFornitoreId] AS [LabirintoFornitoreId],
    [Extent1].[LabirintoCommercialistaId] AS [LabirintoCommercialistaId],
    [Extent1].[LabirintoConsulenteDelLavoroId] AS [LabirintoConsulenteDelLavoroId]
    FROM [dbo].[company] AS [Extent1]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `Console.WriteLine(companies);` should be `Console.WriteLine(row.blah);`
2. You need to call `.ToList()` and then loop through the collection. Query is evaluated when you call `ToList()`.

With `foreach` that you have coded, you get each `company` into row. you can access properties of `company` from `row`.

Lets assume your comany's structure is this

```
public class company
{
   public int companyId {get;set;}
   public string companyName {get;set;}
}
```

Your code should be

```
foreach (var row in companies.ToList())
{
  Console.WriteLine("CompanyId:"+row.CompanyId.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine("CompanyName:"+row.CompanyName);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @AlessioBacin : if you use above foreach, that should lead to the expected result.

Comment: Thanks a lot... i forgot the "ToList" in "foreach (var row in companies.ToList())"

Comment: @AlessioBacin : query will not get evaluated until you call ToList()

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

It's because type of companies is `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Company>` and the `ToString()` method of it returns the query.

When you use `Console.WriteLine(somthings)` the `ToString` method of somethings will be used to output data, so you will receive the `ToString` result that is query text.

How can I retrieve values?

To get value of a field you can use `Console.WriteLine(row.SomeField);` in the loop to receive value of `SomeField` of row.

**Note**

Remember that `Console.WriteLine(row);` will output type of you company class and the output will be a class name for each row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to pass row object

```
Console.WriteLine(row);
```

Comment: Sorry, i pasted the wrong code... it was already "Console.WriteLine(row);"

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the query itself, because `companies` contains the query.

What you want to do is, run the query (foreach will do), and iterate over the result-set (you are already doing it), and for each row in the result-set, print the details you want, like

```
foreach (var row in companies) //row is each row in result set of query companies
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.SomeProperty); //row, not companies
    Console.WriteLine(row.SomeOtherProperty);
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```